# Rails update database approach

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What is the usual approach when I want to read from a text file and update my database.

Firstly I check if the record exists using a unique attribute (let's say 'title'), if not OK I just create it. But if it exists, and one or more of its attributes are updated, then I go through all its attributes and compare the old ones with the new ones? Is there a less expensive way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add index for the uniq field
2. You don't need to go through all the attributes, check with `record.changed` return anything [ if there is no change, it will return empty array ]. If it doesn't then don't update, otherwise update your record.

**More advanced:** insert to your text file another field which the `updated_at` value from the record, if that value changes next time you update your database, then update your record. It would be faster for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you don't have to worry about duplication or updated if you are sure that the data in the file you are reading from is latest then just declare the field as unique in the database and insert all the new records. for duplicates DB will throw an exception that you can handle by deleting that record and again inserting the new values. insertion and deletion for those few cases will obviously be less expensive then checking all the columns one and one and it will take more effort too.